# React SPA dynamic environment configuration

Tags: reactjs, docker, deployment

I'm building React SPA application from ground up using `create-react-app` and setting up uri address for API server of my SPA. According to official documentation  suggested way is to create environment `.env` files for such kind of needs.  I'm using a continuous delivery as part of development workflow. After deployment React SPA application goes in one Docker container and API goes to another. Those containers are deployed in separate servers and I do not know exactly what uri for API will be, so there is no way to create separate `.env` file for each deployment. Is there any "right way" to provide dynamic configuration for my SPA application so I can easily change environment parameters

**API URI examples in SPA**

```
// api.config.js

export const uriToApi1 = process.env.REACT_APP_API1_URI;
export const uriToApi2 = process.env.REACT_APP_API2_URI;

// in App.js

import { uriToApi1, uriToApi2 } from '../components/config/api.config.js';

/* More code */
<DataForm apiDataUri={`${uriToApi1}/BasicService/GetData`} />
/* More code */
<DataForm apiDataUri={`${uriToApi2}/ComplexService/UpdateData`} />
```

Comment: You're going to need to expand on "goes into a docker container" and "deployed", as the answer lies in this part of the configuration.

Comment: Do you know what URL you’re going to be giving to end users at the point you deploy?  That’s probably the URL you need to put in the environment file.

Comment: How many API servers do you have? Do you know the full path of API urls?

Comment: up to 5 URI in average. I do not know the full path of API.

Comment: If you don't know the API url how do you hit the API server from your SPA? Is the API path something similar to your SPA path? Can you give some samples

Comment: Updated question with samples

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that you build your frontend code in some `dist` folder that will be packed by Docker in the image. You need to create `config` folder in your project that also will be added in `dist` folder (and obvious, will be packed in Docker image). In this folder, you will store some config files with some server-specific data. And you need to load these files when your react application starts.

The flow will be like that:

1. User opens your app.
2. Your App shows some loader and fetches config file (e.g. `./config/api-config.json`)
3. Then your app reads this config and continues its work.

You need to setup Docker `Volumes` in your Docker config file and connect `config` folder in Docker container with some `config` folder on your server. Then you will be able to substitute config files in a docker container by files on your server. This will help you to override config on each server.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Where better to store that fetched config data? Some kind of storage like Cookies or in localStorage?

Comment: @Anton up to you. If you are using react with redux, you can just store this config data in redux. Or create separate class `ConfigManager`.